# Como enviar imágenes de webcam con de nodejs a backend python

Tags: python, nodejs

@kikocorreoso muchas gracias por fin logre hacer andar el codigo como prometi aqui publico un enlace con el codigo en mi github: https://github.com/sasuki-chan/nodejs-con-python

El archivo README tienen que verlo primero, el codigo del archivo server.js tanto como el del script en python estan muy bien entendible gracias a los comentarios que puse en el codigo.

Espero que este codigo les sea de mucha ayuda

Este era el problema que tenia:

tengo un servidor en nodejs que recibe las imagenes de la webcam que son tomadas por el usuario, en la parte que falla es cuando intento pasar la imagen que recibe nodejs a python para que con la libreria opencv la procese me aparece este error:

```
 events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
 Error: IndexError: list index out of range
at PythonShell.parseError (/home/kira/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:183:17)
at terminateIfNeeded (/home/kira/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:98:28)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/kira/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:88:9)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
----- Python Traceback -----
File "mostrar_imagen.py", line 14, in <module>
  main()
File "mostrar_imagen.py", line 8, in main
  imagen_dir = sys.argv[1]
```

Si alguien ya ha intentado hacer esto antes, me gustaria que me ayudara con un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

Uso la libreria python-shell para conectar nodejs con el python
y la libreria formidable que recibe el archivo

Este es el codigo que tengo del lado del servidor.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
GLOBAL.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var port = process.env.PORT ||8080;
server.listen(port);
var fs = require('fs');
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('mostrar_imagen.py');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

       ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   app.get('/', function(req,res){
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        res.sendfile(__dirname, + 'index.html');
   });
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 app.post('/upload', upload);

function upload(req, res){
 if (req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
   // parse a file upload
   var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
   var files = []
  form.uploadDir = "upload";
  console.log("Se ha recibido el formulario");

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Se ha recibido el formulario:\n\n');
  console.log(files)
  res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
// aqui intento iniciar el script de python pasandole el argumento de la
// imagen
pyshell.send(files.upload);
});
return;
 }
}
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 console.log('Servidor corriendo en https:localhost:8080')
```

ahora mi codigo de python:
      #!/usr/bin/env python

```
  import numpy
  import cv2
  import sys

  def main():
     #El argumento sys.argv[1] es el que me genera error cuando inicio 
     #el script por medio de nodejs le paso el argumento de la imagen de la
     # webcam, nodejs recibe la imagen del navegador en formato jpeg asi que
     #he investigado que es uno de los formatos correctos.
     imagen_enviada_por_nodejs = sys.argv[1]
     imagen= cv2.imread(imagen_enviada_por_nodejs)
     cv2.imshow("Ventana de imagen", imagen)
     cv2.waitKey(0)

     if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

nodejs cuando recibe la imagen por medio de console.log esta es la informacion
que me da:

```
  { webcam: 
     { domain: null,
        _events: {},
       _maxListeners: undefined,
         size: 2727,
        path: 'upload/upload_00ee34b93cbde97df319d493bb3dcefb',
        name: 'webcam.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        hash: null,
        lastModifiedDate: Fri Jun 10 2016 20:14:00 GMT-0600 (CST),
        _writeStream: 
            { _writableState: [Object],
               writable: true,
               domain: null,
               _events: {},
                _maxListeners: undefined,
                path: 'upload/upload_00ee34b93cbde97df319d493bb3dcefb',
                fd: null,
                flags: 'w',
                 mode: 438,
                 start: undefined,
                 pos: undefined,
                 bytesWritten: 2727,
                 closed: true } } }
```

en resumen he probado la imagen que me guarda en la carpeta upload ejecutando el script desde la terminal de ubuntu y la imagen la lee perfectamente el error esta en que no se como pasar la imagen que recibe nodejs al script de python.

muchas gracias por sus respuestas cada vez estoy mas cerca de lograr
esto, cuando lo resuelva voy a compartir el codigo en github espero que ha alguien mas le sirva.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código Python que te genera ese error?, ¿has probado si el script python funciona sin usar *python-shell*? En principio, según tu descripción, no es necesario comunicar nodejs con python ya que el proceso se puede hacer independiente.

Comment: ya agrege lo que me has pedido @kikocorreoso

Comment: El error puede aparecer si hubo errores durante la carga de la imagen, en cuyo caso la variable `imagen` valdría `None`. Prueba a mostrar esa variable y si es `None`, el error está en `imread`. Quizás el nombre o ruta del fichero no sean correctos.

Comment: Como comenta @JLDiaz, parece que la imagen está corrupta o no accede correctamente a la misma. Si la imagen parece correcta, por ejemplo, se puede abrir con un visor/editor de imágenes sin problemas, por favor, sube la imagen que da error en Python pero no en otras aplicaciones a algún sitio y probamos en las mismas condiciones.

Comment: @kikocorreoso  he modificado la pregunta enormemente ya he identificado en lo que  estoy fallando que es que no se como pasarle el parametro de la imagen que recibe nodejs a python y que python lo reciba

Comment: @JLDiaz he modificado la pregunta enormemente ya he identificado en lo que  estoy fallando que es que no se como pasarle el parametro de la imagen que recibe nodejs a python y que python lo reciba

Comment: En esta línea `imagen= cv2.imread("imagen_enviada_por_nodejs")`, lo que hay entre paréntesis debería ir sin comillas, `imagen= cv2.imread(imagen_enviada_por_nodejs)`

Comment: @kikocorreoso ya he modificado el script de python y aun no funciona tenia mucha esperanza que fuera eso pero no fue asi, ya detecte donde es donde fallo que es pasarle el parametro de la imagen hacia python.  porque cuando ejecuto el script en la terminal sin pasarle alguna imagen en la consola me lanza ese mismo error. asi que es ese es mi error.

Comment: @kikocorreoso dentro de poco compartire el codigo de lo que tengo en github para que me ayudes de mejor maner ya que solo asi me imagino que ha de ser mas dificil

Comment: https://github.com/sasuki-chan/nodejs-con-python   aqui esta mi codigo en github completo desde el lado del navegador cuando toma la foto el usuario, el lado servidor cuando recibe la imagen y la intenta pasar a python, y el script de python que quiero que lea la imagen gracias a la libreria open cv @kikocorreoso

Comment: @kikocorreoso mirate el archivo leeme antes de ver el codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, después de ver un poco mejor el ejemplo he creado un pequeño ejemplo reproducible. En la parte node he hecho lo siguiente:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var options = {
    // el python path lo puedes sacar usando 
    // > which python 
    // en la línea de comandos
    pythonPath: '/ruta/completa/al/ejecutable/python',
    // Esta será la ruta absoluta a la carpeta donde está tu script python
    scriptPath: '/ruta/al/fichero/python',
    // Esta es la ruta absoluta a tu imagen obtenida mediante node
    args: ['/ruta/absoluta/a/python.jpeg']
};
PythonShell.run('tu_fichero.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution 
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

Lo que va dentro de `PythonShell.run(...)` es similar a si en la línea de comandos haces:

```
python /ruta/al/fichero/mi_fichero.py /ruta/absoluta/a/python.jpeg
```

cuando recoges los parámetros que le pasas al ejecutable python usando `sys.argv` el parámetro 0 es el nombre del script y el parámetro 1 es la ruta a la imagen, en este caso.

La parte Python sería:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import cv2

path = sys.argv[1]
print(path)
imagen = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow("Ventana de imagen", imagen)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Si todo ha ido correcto debería salirte una ventana con el logo de Python.

Comment: lo probare ahora para ver si por fin resuelvo esto

Comment: muchas gracias @kikocorreoso por fin lo logre xD, dentro de poco publicare el codigo ya funcionado perfectamente en github espero que a alguien mas le sirva, muchas gracias fuistes de gran ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

@kikocorreoso muchas gracias por fin logre hacer andar el codigo como prometi aqui
publico un enlace con el codigo en mi github: https://github.com/sasuki-chan/nodejs-con-python

El archivo README tienen que verlo primero, el codigo del archivo server.js tanto como el del script en python estan muy bien entendible gracias a los comentarios que puse en el codigo.

Espero que este codigo les sea de mucha ayuda

Comment: Está bien que publiques la solución, pero quizás en lugar de hacerlo como una respuesta a tu pregunta mejor deberías editar la propia pregunta añadiendo una sección del estilo: "Solución final"

Comment: @JLDiaz **no**. No se deben colocar cosas como *solución final* o semejantes en las preguntas.